# Bot will not disconnect from VC but won't raise any errors [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

My bot should disconnect from a Voice Channel when someone runs the disconnect command.

> My bot does not disconnect from the Voice Channel

> But it also does not raise any errors

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def disconnect(ctx):
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    if not vc:
        await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel.")
        return

    await vc.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the voice channel!")
```

> This code is the code that another StackeOverflow user showed me, yet it doesn't work.

> When no one is in the Voice Channel it sends the if not in vc message, so the channel clearly has been found

> When someone is in the vc, it sends the: "I have left the voice channel!" message yet it never actually left

Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how could I fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `voice_client` of the voice channel when the bot connected to this voice channel, so you cannot disconnect the bot if you don't have it.

Look in your code where you used `channel.connect()` and this returns the voice_client which you need to use it in disconnect.

You're wrong when you want to use ctx, it used for who wrote the command and not the bot.